# How to inherit the service defintion (from a bundle) in symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony6

I want to overwrite  method "foo" of service located in a vendor package:

```
class SamlProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
    protected $userProvider;
    protected $userFactory;
    protected $tokenFactory;
    protected $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, ?EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    protected function foo()
    {
        ....
    }
```

I create my own service and extend the vendor service:

```
class SamlUserProvider extends SamlProvider
{
    protected function foo()
    {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}
```

Now I need to define the dependencies in the service.yml which I have no clue about because it is a vendor package.

How can I inherit the service definiton from the child class?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question then all you really need to do is to change the class of the original service.  Something that can be done with a compiler pass:

```
class Kernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Or use the actual service id if it's not the class name
        $definition = $container->getDefinition(SamlProvider::class);
        $definition->setClass(SamlUserProvider::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was searching for. Do you know how I could extend the service definiton by a custom service?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.  There is the notion of [parent services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html).  You can also add/modify dependencies using the same pass logic as shown in the answer.  And then of course there is always service decoration.  If none of these approaches seem to work then consider posting a new question with a specific example like you did in this one.