# How to replace symfony service class, without changing anything else

Tags: php, symfony

I need to change a few lines in one of Symfony services
(to be more specific I need a feature/bugfix that was added in 6.2 while staying in 5.4)

So I copied the service class to my project, did the change and replaced the class in `services.yml`

```
  messenger.senders_locator:
    class: 'App\Overwrites\Symfony\SendersLocator'
```

But now I am getting an error stating:

```
Cannot autowire service "messenger.senders_locator": argument "$sendersMap" of method "App\Overwrites\Symfony\SendersLocator::__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you should configure its value explicitly.
```

The issue is that `$sendersMap` is a migacally created parameter, that is assigned to the original service and recreating it in my application would require a lot of work.

How can I tell Symfony to only replace the class, but keep everything else about the service unchanged?

Comment: You can try [decorating the service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html).  How practical this approach is depends on the service itself.  You can also write a compiler pass which [finds the service definition and simply changes the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562744/how-to-inherit-the-service-defintion-from-a-bundle-in-symfony/74563955#74563955).

Comment: @Cerad It worked. Add it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Two approaches were suggested.  Not really clear which one worked.  Perhaps both did.  In any event this is a duplicate question.  I'd suggest voting for whichever one you used.