# How to override a Event Subscriber in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to override a method in my `EmailEventSubscriber` to send a client specific email.

I have a common class for all the clients in a seperate repository. (this is in vendor folder)

```
class EmailEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    const EVENT_CLOSED = 'attempt.closed';

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // the higher the priority the earlier the method is called
        return array(
            self::EVENT_CLOSED => array(
                array('onClosed', 20),
                array('onAttemptClosed', 10)
            )
        );
    }

    public function onAttemptClosed(GenericEvent $event)
    {
         $this->fireEmailToClient();
    }

}
```

The `EmailEventSubscriber` is common to all the clients, so can not change the code in `fireEmailToClient()` method.

Instead I created a new class `ClientEmailEventSubscriber` in the client repository and did override the `fireEmailToClient()` method as below.

```
class ClientEmailEventSubscriber extends EmailEventSubscriber
{
      protected function fireEmailToClient()
      { //custom email code here }
}
```

The problem is I am getting 2 emails now. One from the original EventSubscriber with the common code and the other with the custom code.

How can I make sure I only get the overridden email content?

Comment: One approach is to just [change the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562744/how-to-inherit-the-service-defintion-from-a-bundle-in-symfony/74563955#74563955) of the subscriber service.